# Calculating frequency of polygon types overlapping coordinate point

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, time-series

I have shapefiles of sea ice coverage for multiple days of the year. At each time-point (day) the sea ice is split into different polygons which corresponds to different ice types (i.e. fast ice, consolidated ice, etc). I have four coordinate points and I would like to obtain the frequency or the counts of the different polygon types occurring at those specific coordinates along the whole year.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163971/identifying-number-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis)

Comment: Please clarify what's in each shapefile. Is it one shapefile per day? Or maybe one shapefile for the whole year for a specific region? Something else?

Comment: I think this question is sufficiently different from the one identified above that I would recommend against closing.

Comment: Hi @Llaves, originally I received one single shapefile for each year which, for each day, had the different polygons. Since I did not know how to work with the file all lumped together I split it in different layers for each day with the "Split Vector Layer". So I have both files, all days together in one single shapefile with two classes "date" and "ice type" or each day as a single shapefile. For each day there are 6 different types of ice or polygons, although not all polygons appear in all days since there are some days of ice free conditions. It's just for a specific region.

Comment: can you share the all-year shapefile, or perhaps a few days worth (if it's large)? I think a spatial join might be a viable approach, but hard to tell without seeing the data

Answer (score 2):

This approach is probably tedious -- not recommended if there is another way.

(1) "Split Vector Layer" tool to split the original layer to 6 layers as per the type of ice.

(2) Run **Union** tool (in the `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`) to divide polygons at overlaps.

[image]

(3) This returns a new layer 'Union'. As the attribute table of 'Union' shows only the original polygon id, we need to calculate `counts` by an expression `count("id", group_by:= geom_to_wkt($geometry))`.

[image]

(4) Lastly, activate *Identify Features* tool and click on your observation point to find the `counts`.

[image]

(5) Problem is, you have to repeat above process 6 times (for whole ice classes)... ...